# Finding a Term of a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

This is from Fitzgerad's *Advanced Calculus*, problem 2.1.4:

For the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined in Example 2.3:
(a)What are the terms $a_{10}, a_{20}, a_{30}$?
(b)Find the second index $n$ for which $a_n = 1/4$ and the fourth index $n$ for which $a_n = 1$.
(c)For $j$ an odd natural number, set
\begin{equation*}
    n = \frac{j(j+1)}{2} + \frac{j+1}{2}
\end{equation*}
and show that $a_n = 1/2$.
(d)Show that $\{a_n\}$ does not converge.

And Example 2.3:

Consider the sequence whose initial terms are as follows:
{a_n} = {1, 1/2, 2/2, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4, 1/5,...}. The sequence whose first 11 terms are displayed above can be more formally defined as follows. Since for any natural number $j$,
\begin{equation*}
 1 + 2 + ... + j = \frac{j(j+1)}{2}
\end{equation*}
for an index $n$ written as $n = j(j+1)/2 + k$, where $1 \leq k \leq j + 1$,
\begin{equation*}
 a_n = \frac{k}{j + 1}
\end{equation*}.

I found answers for the first two parts by simple brute force, which I don't love but it got me the answers; the pattern is pretty easy to recognize (using the natural numbers, start with p/q and p,q = 1, iterate q once and start p back at 1 and iterate until equal to q, repeat). I'm getting stuck on the 3rd and 4th parts, I think because the wording is strange to me. How should I prove that $j$ being an odd natural number forces the index to be 1/2? There's no rules given for how to find $k$, and thus I can't find $n$ or $a_n$. A statement in the example clarifies that I'm basically going to be proving that there are an infinite number of occurrences of 1/2 in the sequence, which intuitively seems correct (an infinite number of natural numbers $\implies$ infinite number of fraction that reduce to 1/2).

(The problem statement and the example are formatted exactly as the book has them, to make sure I noted everything correctly)

Comment: Thank you for giving all the information for the question , very few people bother to be this good. J being odd doesn't make the index to be anything , J is the index , just put an of odd number for the index and calculate the resulting value , remember for the convergence the terms need to tend to zero but for all the odd terms you have a constant value that will blow up the sum

Comment: You should by now have spotted that $n=\frac{j(j+1)}{2}$ gives $a_n=1$. The next case of $a_n=1$ is when $n=\frac{j(j+1)}{2}+(j+1)$, so  $n=\frac{j(j+1)}{2}+\frac{j+1}2$ if meaningful gives $a_n=\frac12$.  And it is meaningful if $n$ is an integer, i.e. $j$ is odd

Comment: Part (d) can piggyback of the comment of @Henry.  As $n \to \infty$, you will have one set of numbers that tend to $0$ (e.g. $1/10, 1/11,  1/12, \cdots$) and another set of numbers that all equal $1$ (e.g. $10/10, 11/11, 12/12, \cdots$).  Therefore, the sequence can't be convergent, because the sequence has *at least* two accumulation points, $(0)$ and $(1)$.

Comment: Actually, not that it matters, every rational number between $0$ and $1$ will be *hit* an infinite number of times, and therefore will be an accumulation point.  For example, $(5/12), (50/120), (500/1200), \cdots$.  So, bizarrely, there will be an infinite number of accumulation points.

Comment: Y'all these comments are so helpful, thank you. @Henry, to clarify, it seems like the fact that $j$ is an odd natural number is not so important as the fact that $j$ is a suitable number for an index, is that correct?

Comment: @elpitts it is a question of whether $\frac{j(j+1)}{2}+\frac{j+1}2$  is a suitable number for an index